# Regex replace first letter of every word with second letter

Tags: regex

My tagging system is now as follows:

```
 - @issue
 - @topic
 - @subject
 - #person
 - #otherperson
 - $company
 - $othercompany
```

One of the apps on the Mac (DEVONthink) treats @ specifically and therefore  I would like to change the tagging system into:

```
 - iissue
 - ttopic
 - ssubject
 - pperson
 - ootherperson
 - ccompany
 - oothercompany
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use groups here. Remember group(0) is always the entire matched String, so we use group(2) and group(3) for the second letter and then the rest of the word:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"@issue"
                      ,"@topic"
                      ,"@subject"
                      ,"#person"
                      ,"#otherperson"
                      ,"$company"
                      ,"$othercompany"};

    String regex = "(.{1,1})(.{1,1})(.*)\\s*?";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("");
    for (String word : words) {
        m.reset(word).find();
        String s = m.group(2) + m.group(2) + m.group(3);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

If you know that your words are formed from alpha-numeric characters, you can change the `(.*?)` to a more specific character group. for example `(\\w*?)` or something like that.

If all the words are trimmed, the ending `\\s*?` can be left out too. For example, here this works just fine too: `(.{1,1})(.{1,1})(\\w*)`.

Also, if you know for a fact that the tags start with @, # or $, this can work too: `([@#$])(.{1,1})(\\w*)`

You can also replace `find()` with `matches()`

Comment: `String regex = "(.{1})(.{1})(.*)\\s*?"` is equivalent to `"(.{1,1})(.{1,1})(.*)\\s*?";` and so is `String regex = "(.)(.)(.*)\\s*?";` but lean and clean. :) Since you throw away the first character, it doesn't even needed to be captured, which would make a renumbering of the groups necessary. `String regex = ".(.)(.*)\\s*?";`

Comment: I always go for the more specific and explicit notation to be able to remember what I was trying to do later on!! But yeah, you're right

Comment: When the expressions are equivalent, the one can't be more specific than the other. It's only more verbose. If you prefer it  - for whatever reason, that's fine, Mostafa{1,1}.